# CKEditor issue with Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, ckeditor

I have a problem with CKEditor, it return me this result : `<p style="text-align:center"><span style="font-family:Lucida Sans Unicode,Lucida Grande,sans-serif"><span style="font-size:14px">News content blah blah blah</p>` instead of the text itself. I did successfully loaded the editor to form. Here is the form code :

```
{!! Form::textarea('abstrak', null, ['class' => 'form-control ckeditor']) !!}
```

the view that supposed to show the result :

```
<h5>{{ $jurnal->abstrak }}</h5>
```

and I load the js file from master template :

```
<script src="{{ asset('ckeditor/ckeditor.js') }}"></script>
```

is there something I missed here ? thankyou

Comment: This is how WYSIWYG editors work! They return an HTML representation of the text, alongside formatting. This way, when you want to show this text in the same format, all you do is show the HTML it gave you!

Comment: I know. But why it shows the html instead of the formatted text ?

Comment: Because Laravel blade will use htmlentities. You want to use `<h5>{!! $jurnal->abstrak !!}</h5>`

Comment: It's working! Thankyou so much

Comment: Then please accept the answer below so that other users with the same issue can find it easily

Comment: Done it @theomessin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instruct Laravel Blade to **not** escape HTML characters by replacing your code with

```
<h5>{!! $jurnal->abstrak !!}</h5>
```

Comment: content/image formatting is not working